# Explanation of => in this Javascript code

Tags: javascript

While working on an FreeCodeCamp challenge, I always compare my code to the actual solutions on the FreeCodeCamp Github. I just don't understand this one :

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // sort and find right index
  var index = arr.sort((curr, next) => curr > next)
    .findIndex((currNum)=> num <= currNum);
  // Returns proper answer
  return index === -1 ? arr.length : index;
}

getIndexToIns([40, 60], 500);
```

Could someone explain to me please the use of 
    =>.
Is it some equivalent of these 
    { } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=>` is an arrow function, it's a ES6 feature and instead of typing

```
function() { console.log("hello world"); }
```

you can type:

```
() => console.log("hello world");
```